# VREP IMU plugin: Transform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot be empty

Tags: ros, imu, rviz, visualization, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
I am trying to simulate IMU sensor using this IMU plugin in V-REP and visualize results in rviz.
https://github.com/bartville/vrep_plugin_imu

But I get following error in rviz:

```
Invalid argument passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot be empty
```

I think `frame_id: ' '` which is empty, is a problem but I don't know how to set it in V-REP or rviz.

Please somebody help, I completely do not understand what is wrong...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299654/vrep-imu-plugin:-transform-argument-source_frame-in-tf2-frame_ids-cannot-be-empty/) by [BuxBleed](https://answers.ros.org/users/36175/buxbleed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-08-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-05**:
I'm sorry, but you're question does not follow the support guidelines. Please review them, especially the sections about not posting screenshots of console output. If you want to update it to remove the images, let me know and I'll re-open it.

**Comment by [BuxBleed](https://answers.ros.org/users/36175/buxbleed/) on 2018-08-05**:
Ok I updated post

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-05**:
I would suggest to also show the IMU message as the `frame_id` field of the header is empty, which seems very much related (or could be a red herring).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at [the code](https://github.com/bartville/vrep_plugin_imu/blob/37b7aa7768a368bb9f358dee57ef49a2ec63ed30/src/ros_server_imu.cpp#L134) for the IMU vrep plugin I don't see it setting the `frame_id` field. That is most likely the cause here.

---

Edit:

> But how is the function or class property name to set `frame_id` for given String ?

I'm not sure what you're asking, but to set a proper frame id:

```
fl.header.frame_id = "<insert some frame name here>"
```

---

Edit2: I'm not a VREP user, but the warning shown [here](https://github.com/bartville/vrep_plugin_imu/blob/37b7aa7768a368bb9f358dee57ef49a2ec63ed30/src/ros_server_imu.cpp#L136-L138) sounds like something to pay attention to:

> ```
> // Quaternion code added
> ```

```
// But It's not from IMU Sensor but from V-Rep simGetObjectQuaternion() Function
// BE CAREFULL When you use it
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BuxBleed](https://answers.ros.org/users/36175/buxbleed/) on 2018-08-05**:
But how is the function or class property name to set `frame_id` for given String ?

**Comment by [BuxBleed](https://answers.ros.org/users/36175/buxbleed/) on 2018-08-05**:
Thanks ! That's what I meant.

**Comment by [BuxBleed](https://answers.ros.org/users/36175/buxbleed/) on 2018-08-05**:
Thank You very much. That was the problem. Everything works now.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-05**:
It would be very nice if you could submit a pull request against `bartville/vrep_plugin_imu` that contributs your fix. Future users would then not run into this issue and you'd save them some time (and possibly frustration).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-12**:
Issue: [bartville/vrep_plugin_imu#2](https://github.com/bartville/vrep_plugin_imu/issues/2).